# Compare two string and display number of mismatching words from string

Tags: javascript, php, html, string, jscript

I know there are many techniques and methods to comparing two `Strings`, and find out if two `Strings` are equal or not.
I want to do something like this:

```
Var Str1 = "Hello How are you?";
var Str2 = "Hello I am ravi.";
```

To compare `str2` with `str1` and display the number count of mismatching words.
Both strings contain 4 words each. It should display you missed three words from `str1`.

I have one web page (web task) where a user needs to listen an audio and transcribe it. So I want to know how many words user misses from the transcribed original audio.

Comment: What if the user misses a word entirely, such that the strings don't have the same number of words? E.g., if the "correct" string is "Hello how are you?" and the user says "How are you?", they've only missed one word. Even if both strings have the same number, I would argue that "Hello how are you?" and "How are you today?" only has two mismatches, not four mismatches...

Comment: that would be only one word missing from str 1 which is Hello. It does not matter how many words entered by user.  user can might write str2= hello how are you? I am sick but will be fine soon. but it contains the words hello how are you, so should considered as correct match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as simple as converting both the strings to an array and then computing the difference of arrays.

```
$arr1 = explode(' ', strtolower($str1));
$arr2 = explode(' ', strtolower($str2));
echo 'You missed ' . count(array_diff($arr1, $arr2)) . ' words from str 1';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use explode to convert the `Strings` to `Arrays` and count the difference between the two `Arrays`:

```
$Str1 = "Hello How are you?";
$Str2 = "Hello I am ravi";

$st1 = (explode(" ", $Str1));
$st2 = (explode(" ", $Str2));


$result = array_diff($st1, $st2);

echo count($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Find and format difference between two strings in PHP

Try This : https://coderwall.com/p/3j2hxq/find-and-format-difference-between-two-strings-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You can trim the chars like ',', '?' in the string. Then trans it to words array, and remove the duplicate one. Last compare the difference between user input arrays and standard arrays.

```
// parse a string to array
function words($string)
{
    return array_unique(explode(' ', str_replace(['?', '.', ','], '', $string)));
}

dd(array_diff(words($array2), words($array1)));  //here user input array2 is the first parameter.
```